# java calculate pathname difference

Tags: java

Is there an open source library that, given ...

```
/a/b/c
/a/b/c/d/e
```

would return ../..

or for that matter given

```
/a/b/c/d
/a/b/c/e
```

would return ../d

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind passing by converting your `Strings` into `URI` then this latter one has the method `relativize` which should do exactly what you want, take a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#relativize%28java.net.URI%29).

Comment: That is a truly devious idea for which I applaud you.